# preg_match_all mention user @ Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, preg-match, mention

I would like to find the mentioned user in a post and save it in a table. Here are all user names entered which are written in the post behind a @ sign and found in the table "User" are found and the ID is stored by the user. Unfortunately, I can not find any users and therefore not the user ID. How can I find the ID from the user?

```
$msg = I am a post and mention @username1 and @username2

      preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/', $msg, $mentionedUsers);

                foreach ($mentionedUsers[0] as $mentionedUser) {

                        $foundUser = User::find($mentionedUser);
                        if ($foundUser) {
                            $foundUserId = $foundUser->id;
                        }

                    $mentionedUser_save = new Mentioned_post_user;
                    $mentionedUser_save->user_id_lead = Auth::user()->id;
                    $mentionedUser_save->user_id = $foundUserId;
                    $mentionedUser_save->post_id = $post->id;
                    $mentionedUser_save->save();
                }
```

Comment: It seems you need to use `$mentionedUsers[1]`, not `$mentionedUsers[0]`

Comment: Without the contents of `$request->get('body')`, this is hard to assist you with.

Comment: @ceejayoz I adapted the question

Comment: Please, don't change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$mentionedUsers[0]` is an array of whole matches, the strings that start with `@` and then have 1+ word chars. User names are the parts without `@` and are captured into Group 1.

Thus, you need to use

```
foreach ($mentionedUsers[1] as $mentionedUser)
                         ^
```

Then, you will have user IDs without `@` in front.

Also, if you want to avoid matching emails you can add `\B` before `@` in the regex:

```
'/\B@(\w+)/'
```

Then, the `@` char will only get matched if it is not preceded with a word char.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does your solution work even if in the post as in the example several references are available?

Comment: @slickness See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YHgOJ). `preg_match_all` returns all found matches.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have come a step further. I still have to have a mistake somewhere that I can not find. I get the error message: undefined Variable: foundUserId

Comment: @slickness You need to create an array of found users and after filling out `$mentionedUser_save`, append to the array, but all in the foreach block. We do not know the whole code behind, you must do that yourself.

Comment: I have adapted the code again but I just do not get an entry in the database

Comment: @slickness Then it is not the regex problem any longer, check the `User::find($mentionedUser)` part.